# Chart.js bajo MudBlazor

Tags: chart.js, blazor

estoy programando bajo MudBlazor WebAssembbly y estoy intentando graficar valores con Chart.js, de hecho logro graficar los datos, el problema es que no puedo lograr formatear los valores del eje Y ya que los valores son dinero. Actualmente se ve el valor 25874 y lo que quiero es que el valor sea $25.874
Alguien me puede ayudar a lograr esto desde codigo c#, la ia no me ha podido ayudar.

Comment: Varias cosas: (1) Debes agregar un [MCVE] .- (2) Debes agregar las etiquetas C# y .net .- (3) Que yo sepa la MudBlazor no usa Chart.js